# My app rejected with some issues

Tags: ios, app-store, ipv6, appstore-approval

I was trying to publish my app in app store I finished every process they rejected with some reasons, Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required. I'm not aware of this thing can anyone explain me what is this and how to solve this problem because in my mobile I tested app it's working properly.

Comment: Apple talks about it here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html see the chapter "Ensuring IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this June, Apple expects Apps to run on IPV6 networks. Apple has started rejecting Apps which do no comply with this.

NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, AFNetworking 3.x+ all support IPV6

If you are using any other network libraries, please use below link to test IPV6 support http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

Once you have made the relevant changes and tested for IPV6 supp

Comment: how to check that my app is compatible with ipv6

Comment: Once you have setup a IPV6 network, and have your device connected to it  with your App running, network calls should be able to go through without any errors. If it works fine, then you are good to go

Comment: see is there any special code and thing to make your app compatible with ipv6 or not ???

Comment: "If you are using IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses, you will need to update your code, Although all NSURLSession and CFNetwork APIs(including NSURLConnection) already support IPV6"

Comment: Just make sure you are using NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, AFnetworking 3.x or similar CFNetwork based wrappers for Network calls