# App store rejected my app 2 time with same issue

Tags: ios, networking, app-store

I completed my first app and try to submit and app store rejected it 2 time with same reason they send me:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an iPhone
>   running iOS 9.3.2 on Wi-Fi. - During review we were unable to sign
>   into the app as a network error occurred  Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise
>   and resubmit your app for review.
>
> Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app
>   supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.

But i tested in my devices with wifi, cellular every type of network it was working fine now m not getting what is the issue i need a solution.

Comment: What are you using for network fetch, Alamofire or AFNetworking or Native iOS Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has made IPv6 mandatory since this June. but the library currently do not support IPv6. So what you need to do is copy the library in the main bundle and change the following in `NetworkReachabilityManager.swift` file

```
public convenience init?() {
    var address = sockaddr_in()
    address.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(address))
    address.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6) // Change this from AF_INET to AF_INET6

    guard let reachability = withUnsafePointer(&address, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else { return nil }

    self.init(reachability: reachability)
}
```

If you are using Pod in your project, you need to unlock the file to change. But again, when ever you will update the Pods, do remember to change `AF_INET to AF_INET6`

Check You Pod here and select the file as shown

[image]

**Change `AF_INET` to `AF_INET6`** and then you will receive a alert to unlock the file and save the file

[image]

**To test your app for IPv6 addresses** [follow](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/)

Courtesy : [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252672/my-app-rejected-with-some-issues/38253121#38253121)

Comment: Sorry but i not getting the meaning of copy the library in the main bundle ??? Please tell me how ??

Comment: Just like you drag and drop file to you main bundle, copy the downloaded Alamofire library files to you project.

Comment: Forget everything, just find the file `NetworkReachabilityManager.swift` and change as above

Comment: If you are using Pod, you will get the alert to unlock the file, unlock it and then change

Comment: M using alamofire pod file m little confuse ? copy in bundle but how?

Comment: The above code is already there in NetworkReachabilityManager.swift

Comment: Yes its there, but you need to change `AF_INET` to `AF_INET6`, can you see AF_INET somewhere in that code?

Comment: Yes i changed it but it dint ask for unlock , thank you so much now i will submit it again :-) Thank you

Comment: Before submit, please check you network fetch first, for error if any

Comment: I m also using Network Reachability So i have to change there also ??

Comment: I'm not sure because that is just for network availability. but if it has `AF_INET` try to change :)

Comment: Use apple`s latest network reachability class to check for network, apple must be handling IPv6 issues. If crash happened, apple will be responsible :) lol

Comment: hhehehheh hahhaha apple is responsible haha ok i will try to use latest one

Comment: Welcome bro, all the best, Mine code is working fine no issue at my end after the change. Hope your app get approved soon.

Comment: I changed also in network reachability its not working but with with alamofire it was working fine now ..

Comment: Apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class, last updated on 5/5/2016

Comment: They again rejected ?? i m not getting what is the issue now the reason is same

Comment: You have test that for ipv6, I've already shared the link how to test ipv6

Answer (score 2):

See here how `AFNetworking` is handling the IPv6 in their instance. There is class called `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6. You might need that too to handle till the library `Alamofire` comes with the new update.

Its checking for the version 9.0 and above using IPv6 and for below using IPv4. You app might be crashing on devices lower than version `iOS9.0`

```
+ (instancetype)manager
{
    #if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 90000) || (defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 101100)
        struct sockaddr_in6 address;
        bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
        address.sin6_len = sizeof(address);
        address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    #else
        struct sockaddr_in address;
        bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
        address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
        address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    #endif

    return [self managerForAddress:&address];
}
```

Comment: my deployment target is ios 9

Comment: If so, try this in your alamofire library until you get the update for Alamofire

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AFNetworking, then replace the methods in Reachablity.m

```
+(Reachability *)reachabilityForInternetConnection
{

#if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 90000) || (defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 101100)
    struct sockaddr_in6 address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin6_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
#else
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
#endif
    return [self reachabilityWithAddress:&address];

}

+(Reachability*)reachabilityForLocalWiFi
{
#if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 90000) || (defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 101100)

    struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
    bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
    localWifiAddress.sin6_len            = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
    localWifiAddress.sin6_family         = AF_INET6;
    // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr    = htonl(IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM);

#else
    struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
    bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
    localWifiAddress.sin_len            = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
    localWifiAddress.sin_family         = AF_INET;
    // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr    = htonl(IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM);
#endif
    return [self reachabilityWithAddress:&localWifiAddress];
}
```